# CSS and JS not loading on Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've just started to learn Node.js and I wrote the easiest server like this:

```js
// workspace

const p = document.querySelector('p');
p.textContent = 'aleluja';
```

```css
html {
 font-size: 10px;
}

body {
 font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <title>Go go go</title>

 <link href="sheet1.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
 <script src="main.js" async></script>

</head>
<body>

 <p>something</p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

And the server:

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

fs.readFile('index.html', (err, html) => {
   if (err) {
     throw err;
   }
   const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
     res.statusCode = 200;
     res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
     res.write(html);
     res.end();
   });
   server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
     console.log('started');
   });
})
```

My problem is that first time I run this code it worked fine - css and js loaded without problems. But later I was experimenting with PHP and Node.js on the same server at once (using nginx). I failed and because I didn't need it too much (it was just for fun) I gived up and changed all changed to achieve this goal settings (like ports in nginx-conf). And then, after trying to run this code again, it doesn't load sheet1.css and main.js. Why is it so? I turned though all settings back to their default state?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your server logic:

> ```
>    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
>      res.statusCode = 200;
>      res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
>      res.write(html);
>      res.end();
>    });
> ```

The browser asks for `/`, the server gives it the value of the `html` variable.

The browser asks for `/sheet1.css`, the server gives it the value of the `html` variable.

The browser asks for `/main.js`, the server gives it the value of the `html` variable.

---

You need to pay attention to the URL in the `req` object and give the browser what it asks for instead of blindly sending `html` no matter what is asked for.

Note that you will also need to set the correct `Content-Type` response header.

(You should probably also avoid reinventing the wheel and use [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) and its [static module](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) which are designed for this).

---

> My problem is that first time I run this code it worked fine - css and js loaded without problems.

There is no way that could have happened. Possibly you loaded `index.html` from a `file:` URL and bypassed the server entirely.

Comment: So probably it's true that I run this code in other way than I thought (probably by localhost hosted by nginx). I'm happy to know that it's only my fault in running wrong server. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think, as very fist example, going with straight `http` instead of `express` (or any other framework) it's better. Once you know how an http server works in node.js you can go with `express`. This makes a big difference in the learning path.