# How to fix "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Tags: javascript, html

When trying to include my .js file in my html I get the error message: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

I have the html file and the javascript file in the same folder, though I have tried different directories and different paths for the src=... I can't get any to work

My line of html looks like: 
`<script src="index.js"></script>`

I have made sure that the html and the js are in the same directory. I include a css file in my html file and it works, just not for the js file.

Regardless of how I try to include it, I get the syntax error

EDIT: for testing purposes, my js file currently has an alert inside of it:
`alert('hello world');`

I have also checked the network tab and there are no 404 errors there, only status 200.

EDIT 2: So I have looked in my app.js code and have found how I upload(?) the HTML file to the server. I believe the server is taking my index.js and my style.css and making them the exact same text as my index.html, causing the error.

```
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    let myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/public/index.html', 'utf8');
    myReadStream.pipe(res);
```

How could I modify this to upload css and js files as well?

Comment: What does the js file look like?

Comment: sounds like you have html error page in your script file and not the script. The network panel will prove that right.

Comment: The error is in the JS … which you haven't shown us.

Comment: I have edited the post to show what is in the js file

Comment: Re edit: There is no `<` character in the JS you shared with us, therefore it cannot be responsible for the error message. (If you think the JS contains that, then the problem is most likely that the URL you have doesn't provide the data you think it does and you should fix that).

Comment: You're almost certainly getting a 404 response with some HTML. Check the network tab in devtools.

Comment: Are you serving the file from some sort of server? Where does the server look for js files? Does opening the page work if you open it as a regular file, rather than from a webserver?

Comment: I am using nodejs to use localhost for testing purposes, how would I make it look for js files?

Comment: @rsorki — The same way you make it look for CSS files probably.

Comment: I am not making the server look for the CSS file, I link it in my header. I also include jquery which works, just not my own js file.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093151/css-and-js-not-loading-on-node-js-server

Answer (score -1):

This error is often returned when you try to get a file, and you get an error response instead.Try to check the network tab of developer tools to check if there are some errors while getting this file.

Comment: I checked the network tab as suggested and I see no issues there.

Comment: Hey Nicola - welcome to StackOverflow. Please realize that telling someone how to solve their own issue - while certainly helpful! - isn't a solution. Therefore, it should be a *comment* instead of an *answer*. Given that you're a newer user, you may not be able to submit comments, however answers are never a substitute. Instead, try to answer questions that are in a directly "solvable" state :) Happy coding!

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, but this is a big generic issues. Next time I'll post a more detailed solution!:)